# EntityFramework Firebird Database First

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019, firebird, firebird-.net-provider

I am trying to create models from database using Firebird EF from Nuget packages. I am running this command:

`Scaffold-DbContext "User=SYSDBA;Password=xxxxxxx;Database=XXXXXXXXX;DataSource=XXXXXXXXXX;Port=3050;Dialect=3;Charset=NONE;Role=;Connection lifetime=15;Pooling=true;MinPoolSize=0;MaxPoolSize=50;Packet Size=8192;ServerType=0;" FirebirdSql.EntityFramework.Firebird -OutputDir Models`

I am getting this error:

```
`System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ProductInfo' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=3.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor..ctor(Object reportHandler, IDictionary args)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.ReflectionOperationExecutor..ctor(String assembly, String startupAssembly, String projectDir, String dataDirectory, String rootNamespace, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.ProjectCommandBase.CreateExecutor()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.DbContextScaffoldCommand.Execute()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Commands.CommandBase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

`

Comment: you may [run into this issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#microsoftentityframeworkcoredesign-is-now-a-developmentdependency-package)

Comment: Solved with installing nuget package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
But now I have a problem with entity classes, because they are not generated after successful run of previous command. It's only generated context class.

Comment: ok, post what you did to fix it as answer and ask a new question on the new issue

Comment: I have installed from nuget this package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design. Now I just have Context file created in Models folder, but without any Entity classes. That's all. No error prompted.

Comment: right under this question is the [answer box, just type here what you did to fix it and later accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: ok, but I am still not fixed my problem. I need to find a way to pull Entity classes into Models folder. Can someone help me?

Comment: there is still an [open issue about this in firebird tracker](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-798)

Comment: Regarding that, it will not be done soon. 3 years passed, and it is still open issue.

Comment: I know, comment there again and ask for the status about the issue

Answer (score 0):

I have installed from nuget this package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design.